# Type Mismatch when creating a sort

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I keep getting a type mismatch with the following code, particularly the `SortFields.Add` line. I'm wondering what's causing this issue? Thanks!

```
worksheet.select
With worksheet.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add(Rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                                    SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .SetRange = consolidated_sheet.Range("A3:K" & row)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code. What is `Rng`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're after this:

```
With worksheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
        .SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .SetRange consolidated_sheet.Range("A3:K" & row)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With
```

while in your code you had:

- unwanted parenthesis enclosing the SortFields.Add() method parameters
- a dot preceeding a continuation line, instead of the opposite

and where you must:

- have declared rng as a valid `Range` reference